# customer header file not found in a large project in c/c++

Tags: c++, header

I got a header file 'A.h' under 'A' directory contains a line of
     #include "B/B.h"
does it mean the file 'B.h' needs to be under 'B' directory which under 'A' directory ? If the 'B' directory is at the same level as 'A', how do I fix it without changing the code in 'A.h'?  I tried to use '-I' to include the 'B' directory when I compiled, but it did not work. I have to admit either I forget or I have not dealt with a project with a complicated file structure like this one.

Thanks.

Comment: It means the directory level above B should be referenced.  Also this include file hell led me to have only two include files - one precompiled header that includes std library stuff and one that includes the same as that plus all of my own headers.  All .cpp files include them both.  No .h files apart from those two include anything.

Comment: Thanks. It works.  I just included the header that caused the problem to me.

Comment: @Robinson Do you know what is required to do to only include B.h file such as #include <B.h> in this case ?

Comment: Add the path to the B directory (including B/ on the end).